# How should I use this hexadecimal data to send ble command to device?

Tags: python

I have a chinese manual for this ble relay board which seems to state that in order to activate relay #1 the command sent is:

C5 04 as a prefix
12345678 for the password part
AA as a suffix

How do I send this from a python script?  I used this in the past:

```
p = btle.Peripheral("bb:00:00:15:27:19")
s = p.getServiceByUUID("0000ffe0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb") #ffe0
c = s.getCharacteristics()[0]
c.write("e")
p.disconnect()
```

for a different board.  I know the bluepy code is fine, its just the command that I need to change.

I pasted the image translated from the manual:
[image]

After trying this code:

```
  password = '12345678'
  response = c.write('\xC5\x04' + password + '\xAA', withResponse=True)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1on.py", line 54, in <module>
    letsgobaby()
  File "1on.py", line 46, in letsgobaby
    response = c.write('\xC5\x04' + password + '\xAA', withResponse=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bluepy/btle.py", line 168, in write
    return self.peripheral.writeCharacteristic(self.valHandle, val, withResponse)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bluepy/btle.py", line 520, in writeCharacteristic
    return self._getResp('wr')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bluepy/btle.py", line 376, in _getResp
    resp = self._waitResp(wantType + ['ntfy', 'ind'], timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bluepy/btle.py", line 331, in _waitResp
    raise BTLEException(BTLEException.DISCONNECTED, "Device disconnected")
bluepy.btle.BTLEException: Device disconnected
```

Comment: Is this bluepy?

Comment: yes it is ian harvey/bluepy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest to change your output to something like:

```
password = '12345678'            # Or whatever it may have changed to
c.write('\xC5\x04' + password + '\xAA')
```

This way it'll send over the appropriate values according to that documentation.

Comment: Ok well it didnt activate the relay and I got this as a last call...actually posted it in the OP

Comment: Oh wait i got it!  I removed withResponse=True and I just left the c.write command and it works!  Thanks!